# How would you go about printing an arrayList recursively in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist, printing

I just got into Java programming and was recently introduced to recursion. My question is how would I go about printing an arrayList recursively?

Comment: with java it is possible... show us your efforts.

Comment: Sounds like some (absurd) homework assignment.

Comment: In my opinion i wouldn't print an arrayList recursively. I'd print it out by iterating through it. Recursion is more fitting for a tree.

Comment: Do you have to do this recursively? Or would another way also be okay? In that cas look at the foreach-loop

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34063365/1945897)

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with this approach of printing values in a list, but a quick snippet.

```
main(String args[]){
    int i =0;
    printRec(list, i);
}

public static void printRec(List<String> values, int count){
    if (values.size() < 0 || count >= values.size()) {
        return;
     }
  System.out.println(values.get(count));
  printRec(values, count+1);
}
```

Comment: It' not very likely that `values.size()` returns less than zero. If you meant `count`, should probably throw an exception instead.

Comment: @Tom Yes you are right, this was just a quick snippet.. There must be a try catch. Anyways, I dont know why anyone would go through a list recursively and highly dont recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

you can print the elements of your list by using loop as well as indexing

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create new ArrayList.
    ArrayList<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    // Add three elements.
    elements.add(10);
    elements.add(15);
    elements.add(20);

    // Get size and display.
    int count = elements.size();
    System.out.println("Count: " + count);

    // Loop through elements.
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        int value = elements.get(i);
        System.out.println("Element: " + value);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is Length for a method. Array and List doesnt support anything like Length

Comment: Looks a bit like C#. Can't even do `[]` on a `List` in Java. :(

Comment: @Stefan Beike: Length is a property of a C# List. That it isn't java, you see from the upper-camel-case and the usage like a variable, whereas in Java would use .getLength(). Actually Java uses size() on list.

Comment: I've edited my answer,you could try this now

Answer (score 0):

response to printing recursively:

- write a method who take a list, and a start number
- if the start is bigger than list size, do nothing
- else, write the element at start, and call the same method with start + 1

Answer (score 0):

you can also use foreach loop

```
foreach(string items in yourlist)
{
    System.out.Println(items);
}
```